# Database design for Scavenger Hunt Game

Tags: database-design, join, relations

I'm designing a section of my database which links `User`, `Team` and `Hunt`. I would like users to be members of a team but the team can play multiple hunts (so can be used multiple times).

The first idea involves a 'HuntTeam' which links `Hunt` to `Team` directly however I need to know *which* users within the team will be playing so I've added a 'Player' table like below:

[image: idea 1]

The second idea is to remove `HuntTeam` completely and link `Player` directly to `Hunt` so it does the job of linking teams and users playing like below:

[image]

I'm worried that although the second option looks more simple, I would need to run quite a few 'belongs to through' or JOIN methods to reference the teams within a Hunt. Would it

Would you recommend one over the other and if so why? Perhaps you have an alternative solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without `hunt_teams` table, a simple query for the teams playing a specific `Hunt` would require joining `players` with `team_members` and grouping them by `team_id`. A lot more work compared to querying `hunt_teams`. And that’s probably a query you’ll be running often.

I can also imagine that this additional source of truth will be nice to have in the long run. Running some stats or dealing with eventual inconsistencies in the database will be much easier.

So the first schema is one I would go with